# Is there a way to selectively replace content in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas

```
df.replace(['《', '》', ' ,\t'], ['', '', '|'], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

I have a dataFrame in which I want to replace the 3 characters. But these replace all the columns. Can I exclude a particular column in the above code that won't be replaced? For example, I have a column called 'Summary' that I don't want to apply these replacements.

Is that possible?

Comment: df['NAME_OF_YOUR_COLUMN'].replace...

Comment: As you can see , my original code replace for all columns. I want to replace for all columns but a specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with pass `dict`

```
df.update(df.drop('Summary',1).replace(dict(zip(['《', '》', ' ,\t'], ['', '', '|'])), regex=True))
```

Comment: Does this do the exclusion of one column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to exclude `df['Summary`], you can use `.loc` to exclude all columns but one and then replace the strings you need to replace.

I dropped the `inplace=True` because I don't know if that will work.

```py
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Summary'] = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Summary'].replace(['《','》',' ,\t'],['','','|'], regex=True)
```

Comment: This looks promissing.

Comment: I edited some more info into the answer. Let me know if it works.